# SVG transparency on a solid background

Tags: html, css, svg, background, transparent

On a valid background, I need to add transparent holes/images that shows body background.

Like this websites;

[skrill.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYUrn.png)
[skrillex.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnlgJ.png)
I can add it as a image but I should resize it according to resolution. Also I'll add some descriptions under this images.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to achieve this effect:

1. Make the solid background a SVG or PNG, with holes cut through to show the underlying background.
2. Make the transparent images replicate the background.
3. Implement the background with `<canvas>` and use JS to achieve this effect by dynamically redrawing the background.

The sites you linked are using one of these approaches.